# How do I disallow an entire directory with robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have two sites I am currently working on which is a shopping cart and another shopper.  Both are under the same domain name so for example

```
http://example.com/first_url 
http://example.com/second_url
```

Both these URLs have tons of pages below them

```
http://example.com/first_url/product1
http://example.com/first_url/product2 
http://example.com/first_url/product3

http://example.com/second_url/product1
http://example.com/second_url/product2 
http://example.com/second_url/product3
```

How do I disallow the main URL `/first_url` and `/second_url` too and all the subpages and sub directories?  I was thinking something like this but I don't know if this works or not and whether it was the correct syntax

```
Disallow: /first_url/*/
Disallow: /second_url/*/
```

Comment: I think your syntax is right but not sure about the extra /

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't need the trailing slash  to block those directories. This will work:

```
Disallow: /first_url/*
Disallow: /second_url/*
```

This [Google help page](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html) covers this quite well.

Comment: You can just do "Disallow: /first_url". The trailing wildcard is ignored. According to https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: You need Disallow: /url/* to match things like http://www.example.com/url/test?test=1

Answer (score -2):

You can use this as your default `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: first_url/*
Disallow: second_url/*
```

The star will enable everything under that category to be disallowed. You can even disallow one specific thing under that category by typing that specific url.

Comment: This is not different than the accepted answer other than you are missing the starting slash.  Disallow rules in robots.txt should all start with a slash.  That is how all the examples are in [the documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)